# Does selling game hacks based on personal user agreement is legal?

Tags: copyright, online, computer-misuse-act

There are so many websites who sell the game hacks and game companies never sue them for that("because they have their own terms and conditions - that's what I think basically"). So if I sell hacks only if the buyer accepts terms and conditions like" he will be solely responsible for blah blah..", will it be considered legal or illegal?

Answer (score 1):

By analogy, if you sell contract killings 'only if the buyer accepts terms and conditions like" he will be solely responsible for blah blah"' then you won't go to jail? Think again, my friend.

Here are the legal issues:

1. Bypassing copy protection is unlawful access of a computer system - a crime in most parts of the world.
2. Selling something to someone which you reasonably believe will be used to break the law makes you an accessory.
3. A contract cannot infringe the rights of third-parties who are not parties to the contract. Your agreement with A doesn't allow you to damage B.
4. A contract for an illegal purpose is void for public policy reasons.
5. Just because you don't know about prosecutions or lawsuits doesn't mean they aren't happening.

See [MDY Industries, LLC v Blizzard Entertainment, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDY_Industries,_LLC_v._Blizzard_Entertainment,_Inc.).

Comment: I agree with your answer but why gaming companies don't sue the websites that sell the hack.

Comment: The question didn't mention that the "hacks" were for the purposes of sidestepping copy protection.  "Hacks" could just as easily refer to changing run-time data of the program to make a game easier (add lives, give extra in-game currency, etc.).

Comment: 6. Hacks breach the EULA of many games using online servers, making the maker *AND* the user liable in contract breech suits.

Comment: Has any producer of game hacks ever been charged with anything other than breach of copyright?  That is all I am aware of, and these happen quite frequently.

Comment: @Dave google Blizzard vs Glider

Comment: @Dave [And MDY v Blizzard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDY_Industries,_LLC_v._Blizzard_Entertainment,_Inc.). And then there's  [Take 2 v Wyckoff et al](https://dockets.justia.com/docket/new-york/nysdce/1:2019cv11818/529129) - a "hack" is nothing but a rather elaborate mod.