# Game Hacking Legality

Tags: united-states, terms-of-service, florida, hacking, online

Hello I have a question about if game hacking is legal in Florida. What I mean by game hacking is making a software and selling it (not altering the games original code or selling anything with the games code in it, and does not ddos/attack the games servers, however it can be used against other players on their servers but it doesn't attack the server) but the software simply reads certain events in the game and then the program displays information you would normally not have

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does selling game hacks based on personal user agreement is legal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33064/does-selling-game-hacks-based-on-personal-user-agreement-is-legal)

Comment: @Nij the only answer to that question seems entirely wrong.  Just like the only current answer to this question, it has a reference to CFAA.  Given that the question is about accessing one's own computer, I am not convinced by that answer or the answer here that CFAA applies.  If it does, it would have to be explained in a better answer before we closing questions by linking them to answers that are poorly written.  It's possibly a violation of DMCA, but there is no answer there or here which explains why.

Comment: The CFAA is clearly applicable because you are accessing a computer in a way you are not authorised to. And whether the answer is bad or not, the question is asking the same thing, closure as duplicate is the only appropriate response.

Comment: @Nij I am not sure if it's appropriate to close as dup if the two questions are similar, but still different, in the situation when there is effectively no answer to either question.

Comment: And I am very sure that we should close as duplicate when any viable answer to one question will answer the other.

Comment: @Nij well, you have your vote.  I disagree.  I think the other question is more narrowly tailored to asking if a hack having its own TOS makes it legal.  I don't think that's fundamentally the same question as whether reading info, which is exclusively on your own system (but which may be useful in outplaying people on game servers elsewhere), is against the law.  Other than the tag (which is not part of the body of the question), it's not even clear that the wording of the other question makes it about an online game.  The body of the question can just as well apply to a stand-alone PC game.

Comment: Does the software "read events in the game" by accessing data directly from the game server, or is it pulling data that has already been downloaded to the user's computer/device?

Comment: @bdb484 it reads game events by accessing addresses in memory inside of the user's own computer it does not interact with anything outside of the computers memory

Comment: Is this program specific to a small set of programs and is using such a program contrary to the EULA for those programs, or are there uses which do not violate the EULA?

Answer (score 2):

**Generally** that depends on the EULA of the game. And you might violate the EULA you signed in the making of your hack, using the hack or even selling it! Let's spin an example:

Let's assume EULA contains this sentence from the [Rockstar EULA](https://www.rockstargames.com/eula):

> You agree not to, and not to provide guidance or instruction to any other individual or entity on how to:
>
> i [...] display, perform, prepare derivative works based on, or otherwise modify the Software, in whole or in part

In that case, by making it available, you are interfering into the contract (EULA) of your potential buyers with the game server owner - which is [Tortious Interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortious_interference) and illegal.

Using the software, as well as making it is [breach of contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breach_of_contract) and, that can make your whole endeavor illegal as you lost your license.

Heck, even **modding** can be considered a breach of that EULA, as became apparent for some Red Dead Redemption fan: He had already gotten a Cease and Desist on a previous project and then worked on *another* project, allegedly on an *illegal copy* of the (prequal) game... It went to court and it went through Arbitration and ended with a settlement making it for that fan illegal to [**ever** work on **any** Take 2 or Rockstar game-related project forever.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK0COV8CkoM) Oh, and it is entirely up to the company to decide if they *want* to pursue those breaches.

In the worst case, to facilitate your hack, you might need to interact with servers without allowance to do so, which can be Computer Fraud and Abuse Act violations.

Answer (score -1):

### It's illegal

It's a breach of the [Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](https://www.nacdl.org/Landing/ComputerFraudandAbuseAct#:%7E:text=The%20Computer%20Fraud%20and%20Abuse,fraud%20law%2C%20to%20address%20hacking.&text=The%20CFAA%20prohibits%20intentionally%20accessing,what%20%E2%80%9Cwithout%20authorization%E2%80%9D%20means.) which makes it a Federal Crime to access a computer "without authorization" or "in excess of authorization".

What you are proposing is beyond what the ToS allow so you are doing it "in excess of authorization". Thee activity could be defined as either Accessing a Computer and Obtaining Information with a penalty of 1 or 5 years or Accessing a Computer to Defraud and Obtain Value with a penalty of 5 years.

See [MDY Industries, LLC v Blizzard Entertainment, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDY_Industries,_LLC_v._Blizzard_Entertainment,_Inc.).

Comment: Downvoting.  This is unrelated to the question asked.  Obviously the fact of ownership of a computer gives one authorization to access it.

Comment: You don't own the game servers unless you are the game company. That is obviously not the case if you need to ask on Stack Exchange whether creating hacks for said game is illegal.

Comment: Just to show how much of a nonsense this answer is, ending a program by instructing the operating system to terminate the program, without giving the program a chance to shutdown properly, would not be authorized by almost all programs' TOS.  This would be illegal under the standard that your answer proposes.

Comment: @Nij the question stipulated that they would not be initiating communications with games servers.  I get that they were unclear in their wording, but they did make it clear that the extent of their interaction with the game client would be limited to observing what is being done to their own computer.

Comment: "does not ddos/attack the games servers, however it can be used against other players on their servers" - **clearly states** the hack will access information from other servers. And since game events (at least on any game not coded by amateurs) will be processed on the server, the hack must necessarily interact with the information on it. Or, the player is accessing the server in breach of the license. Both mean that they are accessing without authorisation to do so.

Comment: @Nij the knowledge so-gained can be used to have a leg up in the process of accessing the servers.  I can imagine any number of scenarios where this would not be an unauthorized access.  They are talking about seeing something that they weren't meant to see, but after it has already been copied to their system by the operator of the game.  If it's on their system, it's legal for them to observe it.  Accessing events on the server would be "attacking the server".  And the question stipulated that they would not do that.

Comment: @grovkin the CFAA has been massively abused by law enforcement in the past, has it not? *All sorts of dumb things* were counted as "accessing computers"

Comment: @Nij typically such a "hack" will access information that is already on your computer.

Comment: @Nij OP has clarified that your premise is incorrect. Repeatedly characterizing it as "clearly" true sort of gives away that you haven't actually *thought* about whether it is true.